# TextView .setText doesn't work on OnClick method

Tags: android

I have a ListView that resides in a fragment and. list item contains several Layouts, with Textview in each.
I am using an AlertDialog that is supposed to ask the user to write something, then when the user click on the yes button, the code changes the value of the TextView with what the user wrote.
So when the user clicks on an item of the listview, an AlertDialog appears, asks user to write something, and changes the TextView's text of the item.

In my test code I tried a simpler version: The alertdialog appears, the user just has to click on the yes button and then the alertdialog put "test" in the TextView.
Code below:

```
  final View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);
                
            List<ItemListViewModel1> list = listfiller();
    
            ListView testListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.idListViewNotes);
            testListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    
                      LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                      final View edittext_View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edittext_changement_note,null);

                      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                      builder.setTitle(nomNote);
                      builder.setView(edittext_View);
                      builder.setPositiveButton("Valider", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewNote)).setText("test");
                               }
                          }
                      });
     
                      AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                      alertDialog.show();

                }
            });
            testListView.setAdapter(new ItemListViewAdapter(getContext(),list));
```

The problem is that the

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewNote)).setText("test");
```

only works when put outside of the `Onclick` of the `setPositiveButton`.
When this line is inside the `Onclick`, the Textview keeps its previous test.

My question is how can I make it set the text in the `OnClick`?

Also, my listfiller() is a function that fill a list but isn't part of the issue.

EDIT: As requested, here is my ItemListViewAdapter code:

```
public class ItemListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //fields
    private Context context;
    private List<ItemListViewModel1> listeItems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    //constructor
    public ItemListViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemListViewModel1> listeItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.listeItems = listeItems;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listeItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ItemListViewModel1 getItem(int position) {
        return listeItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_note, null);

        //Récupère les infos de l'item pour changer le texte des Textview etc
        ItemListViewModel1 currentItem = getItem(position);
        //On récupère les fameuses infos
        String title = currentItem.getTitle();
        String subtitle = currentItem.getSubtitle();
        String nombre = currentItem.getNombre();

        //On crée les éléments pour en changer les valeurs
        TextView titleTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewNomNote);
        titleTextView.setText(title);
        TextView subtitleTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPole);
        subtitleTextView.setText(subtitle);
        TextView noteTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewNote);
        noteTextView.setText(nombre);


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And ItemListViewModel1 is just an object containing 3 strings and their get methods

Comment: In order to change the textview value you have to change the underlying data store used by the listview and then call notifyDatasetChange(). Can you post your ItemListViewAdapter code ?

Comment: Sure, I added it to my post, look for the EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably get compile error when you try to access view object in the onclick listener of the positive button. Because it's not declared final. Let me show you how can you make your existing code working with a little patch,

```
    testListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  final TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewNote);
                  ...
                  builder.setPositiveButton("Valider", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           tv.setText("test");
                      }
                  });

                  builder.show();

            }
    });
```

### Recommended Solution

The above solution just makes your existing code working but it will not persist when the data size grows. So, the better way is to change the dataset and notify the adapter. Here is the sample code,

```
testListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              final ItemListViewModel1 item = (ItemListViewModel1) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);;
              final BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) adapterView.getAdapter();
              ...
              builder.setPositiveButton("Valider", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       item.setNombre("test");
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
              });

              builder.show();

        }
});
```

Comment: Actually I didn't succeed with your first solution but the Recommended Solution works just fine